# What good is a hash accompanying a program?

Tags: hash

After studying at length about weaknesses in SHA2, length extension attacks, forged signatures, etc. I have to ask why groups like Gnu provide hashes on their program texts?

As long as the public knows how the hashes were generated, a forger could substitute his own malicious code and cook up a totally valid hash for it, so that it would look legitimate.

So it appears that this is "security theater" which looks serious, but has really no way of assuring anything meaningful.

Comment: Was that last paragraph really necessary?

Comment: Related question on security.se: [Does hashing a file from an unsigned website give a false sense of security?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/does-hashing-a-file-from-an-unsigned-website-give-a-false-sense-of-security)

Comment: This really has nothing to do with length extension attacks or forged signatures or the (few) SHA-2 weaknesses (SHA-2 is a strong hash). It has everything to do with the lack of a key.

Comment: Similar question on [unix.se]: [Why compute checksums of downloaded files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215707/why-compute-checksums-of-downloaded-files)

Comment: At my university, hashes of critical software components are printed in the welcome package given to new users of the computing centre. Those are pretty hard to forge. It would, however, be impractical to print those packages themselves.

Comment: Ignoring security entirely for a moment, hashes can also be used to check for corrupted downloads.

Comment: The first two sentences indicate, you believe SHA-2 to be vulnerable to finding preimages to a certain hash value (e.g. with the length extension...). This is wrong. As others have already pointed out: SHA-2 is considered one of the stronger hashes (and pretty much state-of-the-art in practical applications). Even MD5 is still considered secure against preimage attacks (but not recommended any more). And that is still enough if you get the hash from a trusted source.

Comment: Considering websites: It can also make a difference if the HTML is transmitted via HTTPS, and the file download is unencrypted.

Answer (score 7):

Well, if you can assume that the website hasn't been hacked, then providing a SHA2 hash of a program would allow you do make sure you downloaded (from anywhere on the internet) a good version of the software.

You are right, however, that since the method is publicly known, if someone can replace the binary on the site, they can also replace the hash on the site.

This is why a number of sites now publish PGP signatures of their software, instead of a simple hash. Now an attacker would have to forge the signature, which is computationally infeasible. This assumes that you know the valid public key. How do you get the public key? Well, that is another can of worms.

Comment: PGP only helps if the recipient has some way to authenticate the signature. Otherwise it's just one more generation of the chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: @Gilles, true, just look at the abysmal state of the [Tor signing keys](https://www.torproject.org/docs/signing-keys.html.en)

Answer (score 3):

Hashes are useful when the source of the hash is trusted. If you know that you have received the correct hash from a trusted source, and if it is a strong hash (which SHA-2 is), then the hash lets you be sure the file you receive from *any* source is the same as the file that the person you got the hash from had seen on their end. Length-extension attacks are irrelevant: with a strong hash (which, again, SHA-2 is), the *only* way for an attacker to undetectably tamper with the file is to mount a second-preimage attack (we don't think this is feasible even for MD5), or to tamper with the hash itself so you get an incorrect one. If you can trust the hash, you can trust the file no matter where the file came from.

For instance, suppose a program uses many mirrors to ease the load on the download server. Those mirrors may not be fully trusted. However, if the project website itself *is* trusted, and that connection is secure against tampering, the trust given to the information received from the project site can be carried over to the actual files downloaded from the mirror. BitTorrent is one use of this: the torrent pieces are downloaded from untrusted sources, but the torrent file itself comes with the hashes of the pieces (it can also contain the root of a hash tree, which is again unkeyed). So, as long as the **torrent** file is downloaded from a trusted source, the pieces can be verified against the trusted hash.

Organizations like the FSF are more likely to use signatures. With signatures, there's an added check: signature public keys stay the same for a long time, so it is even easier to ensure the public key you received was the real public key (and given that the public key is the correct one, signatures cannot be forged by someone without the private key). But that's an added step that means you don't even have to trust the hash you received for some specific version of the program; if you *do* trust the hash you received, it does protect you against tampered-with programs.

Answer (score 2):

Hashes are not intended to be used against an active attacker, that's what signatures are for.

Hashes are often provided alongside programs so that the integrity of the downloaded file can be verified. Users with unreliable internet access could get a corrupted file, having a hash allows them to easily verify that the download succeeded. Some protocols, like Bittorrent, do this verification automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> As long as the public knows how the hashes were generated, a forger could substitute his own malicious code and cook up a totally valid hash for it, so that it would look legitimate. So it appears that this [...] has really no way of assuring anything meaningful.

You are right that a human attacker able to modify the contents of a website could trivially replace both the program and the hash.

However, downloads are frequently redirected to one of a large number of "mirror" sites while the web-pages are served from the organization's web server. Thus providing a hash on a web-page actually does provide a level of security against attackers that can compromise only a mirror or two, and not the organization's web server.

Additionally, it is sometimes possible to access a web-page containing a hash through http**S** rather than plain http, providing protection against man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks.

Even without http**S**, it is sometimes possible to load a web-page through a different channel to thwart MITM. For example, I can also load a web-page on my mobile phone through the cellular network and check the checksum. This protects against a MITM that can only control my DSL. Without a posted hash, I'd have to download the whole file through each such path and binary compare the files.

Also, consider the case of a virus that searches for and injects itself into binaries. If such a virus runs on a web server, will it be smart enough to locate the corresponding web-page from which the download is linked and replace the hash? Perhaps not.

In short, while you are correct that hashes are not a panacea, there's tons of real-world attacks that can be defended against by using hashes.